# Is there a way to change IExpress options after an executable is made?

Tags: iexpress

I made an executable out of a `jar` archive. Unfortunately, I forgot to check the "Hide File Extracting Process Animation from User" check box. Is there a way to reconfigure this after the executable is packed?
I can re-pack it following the same process but checking that check box, but it just takes too much time.